Transferred ETH to Base
I can see the transaction and the asset on the base network but don't know how to retrieve it.
Sent from: 0x4E25696e5fe9427896E0d2A978C259D712bb81b4
Sent to: 0xF0a6947c74131ff614B526756aa81F2153C9541e
Txn id: 0xc716cfbd17859ca82a09b80fc9383a7924161df005c8a0b62ee650ba8d6f802d

Not, sure what you mean but you did a transfer and funds are on 0xf0a6947c74131ff614b526756aa81f2153c9541e on Base

If you own this wallet 0xF0a6947c74131ff614B526756aa81F2153C9541e  then you have the control otherwise no. Please add more details in your question.

Assuming you own 0xF0a6947c74131ff614B526756aa81F2153C9541e you can just change the network on your wallet to base network and send it where you would like(assuming you have enough of the native asset on Base network which is BSC.  If you have not BSC you will need to send enough to cover the transaction cost).
